# How does percona works and when should be used

Tags: mysql, percona

I recently came across percona, seems like very interesting stuff. I have an basic understanding of what it does but want to know how it is used in industry standard production enviroments and when should one go for percona over standard Mysql. What are pros and cons of both of these. Can anybody throw some light on it ?

Comment: There is MariaDB too. You may want to compare the features against your needs/requirements. For general apps, it is fine to go with any of them.

Answer (score 2):

Percona Server for MySQL is an enhanced drop-in replacement for MySQL. It comes with additional features like a modified InnoDB called XtraDB. It comes with MySQL Enterprise features in an open source fashion - the threadpool, the PAM authentication plugin, and so on. It is 100% open source GPLv2 as well. If you use it with something like HAProxy, it also supports the PROXY protocol.

The pitch for when you go for Percona Server for MySQL over standard MySQL in the [documentation](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/index.html) is quite clear: queries that run faster and consistently, server consolidation, save money on hosting fees, spend less time on tuning and administering (out of the box), higher uptime, and more granularity when troubleshooting.

Some happy users are listed: https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-server/users

I hope this sheds some light on the situation for you. If you're more specific in what your uses and requirements are, there is a good chance we can provide a more specific answer to you as well.